# SVN checkout fails with "Could not read... " error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

```
My PC (client)
OS windows7 32bit
Tortoise SVN ver 1.7.5
```

I've been able to SVN update to the repository and after few month, my coworker tried to checkout whole project (web app) and had svn error.

I tried the same, create new folder and checkout my project then I got:

```
REPORT of '/svnrepos/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read status line: Secure
connection truncated (https://foobar.jp)
```

I did `svn cleanup` as suggested by few people on the web which had no effect.

It seems like every time the error is different. I'm also getting:

```
REPORT of '/svnrepos/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: Secure
```

and

```
REPORT of '/svnrepos/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk delimiter: Secure
```

Also some says there might be a corrupted file in the repository. And I deleted every file one by one to see if particular file is causing this error and no particular file causing this.

I also updated my `Tortoise SVN` version to `1.7.5` which is the newest.

The size of files I'm trying to checkout is about **30 MB** which is not big at all.

I'm done all I can think of but still not able to solve this problem.
Could anyone encounter this before?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried that! But what does it do to svn? Does restart clear something that might be causing?

Comment: I don't know ;) I got similar errors earlier this week and restarting the (apache2-)server helped.

Comment: Is "windows7 32bit" the OS of host with repo or client?

Comment: Its my PC spec (client).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Restarting Apache** fixed the problem. Now I wonder what was the cause of this and why restarting fixes the issue. Thanks to Tobias for mentioning it :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Running in Eclipse I had the same issue but restarting the server where SVN was set-up didn't do the trick for me. I managed to get round this by changing the SVN client in Eclipse to use 'SVNKit (Pure Java)'.

Windows > Preference > SVN > [SVN interface] > 'SVNKIT (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.7.4.9190'

Hope this helps somebody having the same problem.